PySide6 modifies the "QTabWidget" style sheet to have rounded corners But it seems like the background still has right angles
PySide6 modifies the "QTabWidget" style sheet to have rounded corners But it seems like the background still has right angles.

self.DialogueGroup_StackedWidget.setStyleSheet("QStackedWidget {"
                                                       "color: rgb(176, 224, 230);"
                                                       "background-color: rgba(41, 48, 83, 0);"
                                                       # "border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;"
                                                       "border-radius: 15px;}" 
                                                       )

I've been using Google for a long time but haven't found a suitable method

You are asking about QTabWidget, but your code actually uses QStackedWidget. Please make yourself more clear and provide a proper [mre].
